# How to handle Shape when creating a theme for Material Design 3 for compose

Tags: material-design, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I currently have an app written in jetpack compose which uses Material-Theming-Support from `androidx.compose.material:material`.

```
from / import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme

@Composable
fun MaterialTheme(
    colors: Colors = MaterialTheme.colors,
    typography: Typography = MaterialTheme.typography,
    shapes: Shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
)
```

I now plan to migrate to Material3: `androidx.compose.material3:material3` (still in alpha, i know).

However, the theme-composable now doesn't allow any shapes anymore

```
from / import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme

@Composable
fun MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme,
    typography: Typography = MaterialTheme.typography,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
)
```

What should i do now with my old shape definitions?
The material-website only talks how to do that in xml & the [old view-system](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/shape-theming).

Comment: In the [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/material#material3) you can find: // Updates to shapes coming soon

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti if you make a "real" answer out of that, i'll accept it. "Coming soon" is fine with me, since i don't use shapes excessively

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** Now for shapes you can use inbuilt Material api just add latest compose-bom version and material3 library in toml or build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier.clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
```

or let say for rounded shape you can use

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier.clip(shape = CircleShape),
```

or

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier.clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50)),
```

**Old answer:**

[Material Design 3 / Material You still don't have shapes.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/material#material3)
So to use shapes create [composition local](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal#creating-apis),

In directory **ui/theme** create **Shape.kt** Kotlin file in that file paste following code

***Shape.kt***

```
data class Shape(
    val default: RoundedCornerShape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp),
    val small: RoundedCornerShape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
    val medium: RoundedCornerShape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    val large: RoundedCornerShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
)

val LocalShape = compositionLocalOf { Shape() }

val MaterialTheme.shapeScheme: Shape
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalShape.current
```

Now, to use shape in compose

```
shape = MaterialTheme.shapeScheme.large
```

eg. In card compose

```
Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(all = 16.dp),
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapeScheme.large,
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
        border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseOnSurface),
        elevation = 1.dp
    ) {
...
}
```

Edit :
[Check this](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/shape-theming)

Comment: You'll run into issue with this solution if you use multiple different themes with different shapes. However, this seems to be as good as it gets, until we have official support 